# При выполнении `dbms_application_info.set_module()` поля `Action` и `module` остаются пустые

Tags: oracle, plsql

Есть процедура, которая синхронизирует индекс в базе :

```
PROCEDURE UpdateIndex
IS
BEGIN
    dbms_application_info.set_module('MyModule', 'Run');
    dbms_application_info.set_client_info('Sync Index');  
    CTX_DDL.SYNC_INDEX('OBJECT_IDX');   
    dbms_application_info.set_module('MyModule', 'Finished');
    dbms_application_info.set_client_info('Sync Index');       
END;
```

Если запускать процедуру вручную, с IDE - все работает правильно, но, если процедура запускается с бекенда - то в таблице `v$session` поля `module` и `action` почему-то пустые.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3):

Возможно сессия, где была вызвана UpdateIndex, закончилась.
Попробуйте

```
select module, action from v$sqlarea where module='MyModule':
```

или вызовите в той же сессии

```
dbms_application_info.read_module(module, action);
```